# Spring webflux webclient handling mixed response having http status code as 206

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a scenario where the http response from a different web service can contain mixed results. For e.g
Sample Request : POST /fetchdata

```
{
  "empIdSet": [
  {
    "empId": 123,
    "empId": 456
  }
]
}
```

Sample Response:

```
{
   "empDetailsResponse": [
   {
     "id": 123,
     "fname": "Tom",
     "lname": "Smith"
     "status": "Active"
   },
   {
     "id": 456,
     "status": "NOT_FOUND"
]
}
```

The response looks like `Mono<EmpDataResponse>` and the EmpDataResponse contains `List<EmpDetailsResponse>`
The method looks like:

`Mono<EmpDataResponse> fetchData(EmpDataRequest empDataRequest)`

I have ResponseHandler which is interested in !NOT_FOUND list and the ErrorResponseHandler handles cases whose status is NOT_FOUND.

Is there a way i can process my above to handlers once i get the response back from the webclient service class?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can omit using of http status code and annotate your type with `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, if you are referring to the status field in the json response, then its not the http status code, rather it can be anything like 'Suspended', 'Closed' etc. What i am interested is to know how can I use multiple handlers like ResponseHandler and ErrorResponseHadler to the same response output which can have mixed content.

Comment: But what do you mean under "Handler"? WebClient doesn't have such definition...

Comment: Perhaps you need manually grouping your 'EmpDetailsResponse', because I don't know any similar functionality in WebClient.